# Does Windows 7 allow advanced skinning like Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

The Windows 7 Aero interface looks great, but after looking at it for months it gets boring. So I was wondering - is it possible to create advanced skins for Windows 7 that use full Aero capabilities but are redesigned from ground up, including common controls, animations, effects, etc? Windows XP allowed that, although only with a patched uxtheme.dll.

Or do you have to implement a custom shell for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the kicker:

> Windows XP allowed that, although **only with a patched uxtheme.dll**

That doesn't mean that Windows 7 won't have this feature, but it does mean it won't inherit anything from Windows XP written to do this, because the feature you're thinking of was a hack created outside of microsoft.

Comment: Well, in that regard Windows XP doesn't support advanced skinning.

Comment: that's my point - this is not something that's supported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, download the app from the following site (it allows you to use custom themes **WITHOUT** needing to patch!  :)  , meaning no need for taking ownership, updating the system file cache or anything like that).

http://uxstyle.com/

Click the button that says "Play with the bits" to download the installer, and install it (**no** reboot required!).
Next, find a library to download custom themes. Personally, my favorite is here:

http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows7/visualstyle/

If you were doing this in XP, then installing the themes is exactly the same... just copy the theme files into `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes` as you did on XP.

Enjoy the beauty!

Two of my favorite themes:
http://benbackman.deviantart.com/art/Vienna-162878768
http://giannisgx89.deviantart.com/art/Sonye-Theme-for-Win7-v2-155198766 (based on the Office 2010 interface)

While you're at it, here is another great program which compliments custom themes nicely, to change your start button image: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-start-button-changer-released . And someplace to start for new orb images: http://www.deviantart.com/#order=9&q=start+orbs .

ENJOY!  :)

Comment: "Without needing to patch" is a bit misleading. The program you install silently patches your system at runtime. :) The only real difference is you don't have to restart after installing it, at the cost of having it run in the background.

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually replace ("patch") the system files, which is what would normally require the restart (and also, technically, "breaks" Windows). It does, yes, install a driver/service which runs in the background. At a footprint of only 460KB and 0% CPU usage this shouldn't be a concern for even the lowest-end home computers still in use today. But yes, you're right it does run a background service.

Comment: No, I'm not saying it'll slow down your system or anything like that, I'm just saying that it's a bit misleading to say it doesn't affect your system at all. :) Regardless, it's a very cool idea.

Answer (score 0):

A search for "windows 7 aero themes" showed up several sites:

http://www.technixupdate.com/free-custom-aero-theme-for-windows-7/

http://www.anewmorning.com/2009/02/02/windows-7-theme-aero-diamond/

to list but two (which actually point to the same theme).

I haven't checked these out (I'm not running Windows 7 on this machine), so I don't know whether they fulfil you criteria completely.

However, [this site](http://www.coolbuster.net/2009/07/how-to-download-windows-7-aero-themes.html) describes how to download some more from Microsoft:

> 1. Right click any blank space in your desktop and then select 'Personalize'.
> 2. At the right side just a little above 'Aero Themes (7)' line, find 'Get more themes online' and click it.
> 3. You will be redirected to the Windows 7 personalization page.
> 4. Scroll in the middle and you will find downloadable Slide Show Themes.
> 5. Just click the 'Download' button to get your preferred theme which will automatically install as a theme pack file.
> 6. Click to begin download and installation.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP technically didn't allow this--the fact that you had to patch `uxtheme.dll` means it wasn't a feature built into Windows. Windows 7 is the same, nothing has changed--you can still [patch your system](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/2008/11/universal-theme-patcher.html) and use [custom themes](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows7/visualstyle/). The only difference is Windows 7 has Aero, which allows for much cooler styles than XP ever did.